# Gson to POJO, how to read the inner JSON Objects as part of the same POJO?

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a `JSON` like below and would like to convert it using `Gson` to one `POJO`.

I am trying to figure out how to basically cut down the inner nested objects like `desc` to be treated as part of the same Java object, instead of creating a new POJO named `Desc`.

Is there a way to do this with `Serialized Names` to look into nested JSON objects?

Thanks in advance!

**JSON to be converted to POJO**

```
        {
            'name': name,
            'desc': {
                'country': country,
                'city': city,
                'postal': postal,
                'street': street,
                'substreet': substreet,
                'year': year,
                'sqm': sqm
            },
            'owner': [owner],
            'manager': [manager],

            'lease': {
                'leasee': [
                    {
                        'userId': leaseeId,
                        'start': leaseeStart,
                        'end': leaseeeEnd
                    }
                ],
                'expire': leaseExpire,
                'percentIncrease': leasePercentIncrease,
                'dueDate': dueDate
            },
            'deposit': {
                'bank': 'Sample Bank',
                'description': 'This is a bank'
            }
        }
```

**Custom POJO**

```
public class Asset {

private String mId;

@SerializedName("name")
private String mName;

private String mCountry;

private String mCity;

private String mPostal;

private String mStreet;

private String mSubstreet;

private int mYear;

private int mSqm;

@SerializedName("owner")
private List<String> mOwners;

@SerializedName("manager")
private List<String> mManagers;

private List<Leasee> mLeasees;

private DateTime mLeaseExpiration;

private int mPercentIncrease;

private int mDueDate;

private String mDepositBank;

private String mDepositDescription;
```

}

Comment: How about `Map<String, String> desc`?

Comment: @saka1029 I will go this route. For the `lease` object, ill just have a nested Map as well. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I ran into a problem of the `Map<String, Object>` not being able to serialize/deserialize. How do I manage this?

Comment: I tried. It works fine. What happens?

Comment: @saka1029 I have no problems serializing it, but then I get this error: `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Attempted to serialize java.lang.Class: com.walintukai.watchdog.models.Asset. Forgot to register a type adapter?` when trying to deserialize it into a json string: `new Gson().toJson(asset, Asset.class)`

Comment: Define `public class Root { public Asset asset; }` and do `new Gson().fromJson(asset, Root.class)`.

Comment: @saka1029 The json is actually not embedded with the `asset` key as the first object. I have updated the json example to show how it really shows. Also, I fixed the issue with added excludes as such `new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithModifiers(Modifier.FINAL, Modifier.TRANSIENT, Modifier.STATIC).serializeNulls().create();`. My issue now lies trying to store the data with `Active Android`.

Comment: I changed my data and code.  `new Gson().fromJson(asset, Asset.class)` works fine.  Are you calling **fromJson**?